# How to change sa password in SQL Server 2008 express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I have installed SQL Server 2008 express and logging in through windows authentication, it doesn't allow me to do anything. How do i change 'sa' password or gain full privilege in my local computers 2008 express ? I am using windows 7.

Comment: Is your user account an Administrator account?  Also, see this link: http://ashrafur.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/set-sa-password-using-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: Did you enable mixed mode authentication (and choose an SA password) during the install?

Comment: i cannot remember and it's not allowing me to do anything

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to follow the steps described in [Troubleshooting: Connecting to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004%28SQL.100%29.aspx) and add your own Windows user as a member of sysadmin:

- shutdown MSSQL$EXPRESS service (or whatever the name of your SQL Express service is)
- start add the `-m` and `-f` startup parameters (or you can start `sqlservr.exe -c -sEXPRESS -m -f` from console)
- connect to DAC: `sqlcmd -E -A -S .\EXPRESS` or from SSMS use `admin:.\EXPRESS`
- run `create login [machinename\username] from windows` to create your Windows login in SQL
- run `sp_addsrvrolemember 'machinename\username', 'sysadmin';` to make urself sysadmin member
- restart service w/o the `-m -f`

Comment: I had to start the sql service using a trace option to get it to work, and also shut down any service that might try to connect to SQL express (like the Ektron indexing service): `sqlservr.exe -c -sSQLEXPRESS -m -f -T 7806`, then I connected to SSMS just using `.\sqlexpress` for the server name

Comment: Make sure you run your SSMS in elevated mode otherwise you might not get the connection.

Comment: @Rashack comment is a very important point, otherwise your connection will fail if you are not running as the administrator.

Answer (score 66):

If you want to change your 'sa' password with **SQL Server Management Studio**, here are the steps:

1. **Login** using Windows Authentication and ".\SQLExpress" as Server Name
2. **Change server authentication mode** - Right click on root, choose Properties, from Security tab select "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode", click OK
   [image: Change server authentication mode]
3. **Set sa password** - Navigate to Security > Logins > sa, right click on it, choose Properties, from General tab set the Password (don't close the window)
   [image: Set sa password]
4. **Grant permission** - Go to Status tab, make sure the Grant and Enabled radiobuttons are chosen, click OK
   [image: Grant permission]
5. **Restart SQLEXPRESS service** from your local services (Window+R > services.msc)

Comment: This only works if you have the rights to change sa password.

Comment: What if I get "user has no credentials to change authentication mode" in step 2?

Comment: Thanks Worked Perfect, Just you need to be running Management Studio in Admin Mode

Comment: Probably the only end-to-end complete answer for this topic on the internet!

Comment: This answer works, But sometime you need permission to change the sa password, To **Get Permission to Change sa Password** , check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43231188/2218697) link. Hope helps.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't know the existing sa password so this is what I did:

1. Open Services in Control Panel
2. Find the "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" entry and select properties
3. Stop the service
4. Enter "-m" at the beginning of the "Start parameters" fields. If there are other parameters there already add a semi-colon after -m;
5. Start the service
6. Open a Command Prompt

Enter the command:

```
osql -S YourPcName\SQLEXPRESS -E
```

(change YourPcName to whatever your PC is called).

7. At the prompt type the following commands:

> ```
> alter login sa enable
> go
> sp_password NULL,'new_password','sa'
> go
> quit
> ```

8. Stop the "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" service
9. Remove the "-m" from the Start parameters field
10. Start the service

Comment: This worked for us, even when adding a user (as the accepted answer recommends) failed.  We used sqlcmd.

Comment: Sql Server Express 2008 does not start with `-m` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

**This may help you to reset your sa password for SQL 2008 and 2012**

```
EXEC sp_password NULL, 'yourpassword', 'sa'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly if you know `sa` password

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

- Close all Sql Server referencing apps.
- Open Services in Control Panel.
- Find the "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" entry and select properties.
- Stop the service (all Sql Server services).
- Enter "-m" at the Start parameters" fields.
- Start the service (click on Start button on General Tab).
- Open a Command Prompt (right click, Run as administrator if needed).
- Enter the command:

  osql -S localhost\SQLEXPRESS -E

  (or change localhost to whatever your PC is called).
- At the prompt type the following commands:

  CREATE LOGIN my_Login_here WITH PASSWORD = 'my_Password_here'

  go

  sp_addsrvrolemember 'my_Login_here', 'sysadmin'

  go

  quit
- Stop the "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" service.
- Remove the "-m" from the Start parameters field (if still there).
- Start the service.
- In Management Studio, use the login and password you just created.
  This should give it admin permission.